# AJAX post request slow every second time [Django]

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

As a little side-project I created a Django-based Web Application. So far I have created my webpage with basic Javascript. I can successfully get data from the database and create an AJAX POST-request via Javascript. Everything is working BUT there is something that really bothers me:

Every second POST-request takes a significantly longer time to reach the server. For example: Request1 returns successful after 29ms. Request2 needs (for the exact same task!) over 300ms. This goes on and is 100% replicable. I have no idea what the reason for that issue is. I hope someone can guess what the root for this problem is.

[Image of "request-waterfall" from the developer tool.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucgVW.png)

Used Code:

```
//THIS IS THE POST REQUEST IN THE JS-SCRIPT (CLIENT-SIDE)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/update_database',
            data: {
                "habit_name": habits[h].habit_name,
                "meta_data": meta_data
            },
            success: function(result) {
                update();
                console.log('Successful');
            }
        });
```

---

Server-side handling of the POST-request:

```
def update_database(request):

post_dict = dict(six.iterlists(request.POST))
habit_name = post_dict["habit_name"][0]
meta_data = post_dict["meta_data"][0]

change_meta_data(habit_name, meta_data)

data = {
    "Habits": Habit.objects.all().values()
}
return JsonResponse(list(data["Habits"]), safe=False)
```

Update: The problem only occurs when I launch the server on localhost. If I runserver on local IP-adress, it works fine..

Comment: did you manage to identify if the server is responding slowly or the request is being held by your browser?

Comment: @Walucas Honestly, I don't know how I could do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Try checking on your runserver output when the request arrives that second time, and when it returns to the browser (u may use the datetime to do a diff)... that should cover the server side.... I would say if that is fast, the problem would be on your browser.... but I am only guessing here on how to do it

Comment: Nice idea, thanks! I just measured the time of all the server-side calculation / database stuff. conclusion: Server-side shouldn't be the problem, as the time was always around 20ms.

Comment: so looks like its your browser.... did you try using other browsers?

Comment: Yep, just did that. And indeed it works just fine in Firefox! Feel kinda stupid that I didn't try that before.. Always thought Chrome is best to use for Web Development. Anyway, Thanks for guiding me through :) And if you / anyone knows what Chrome's problem migth be, let me know.